# AS400 returns CWBLM0011

Tags: windows, ibm-midrange

I inherited a program in asp, and that program is on windows server 2003.
The program save data on As400 database.
When I try to submit file to upload, it returns the following error:
CWBLM0011 - internal licence error, rc= 6211 .
I tried te suggestions on this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1017519)

but it didn't help me.

what can be the cause of that problem, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Did this program work in the past?  If so, what changed?  Something in the program?  Something on the Server 2003 machine?  Something on the IBM i?

What exactly did you try of the suggestions in the link?

Comment: yes, it did. The server 2003 machine had a problem and then restored. related to the link, I tried to create and delete the key to be sure that I've necessary permissions.

Comment: Clearly, the restore wasn't complete.  Something's off; could be the IBM i Access installation, could even be something relating to the TCP/IP configuration of the Server 2003 machine.  Run 'Check Service Pack' and make sure the latest service pack for IBM i Access is installed on the Server 2003 machine.  There is a program called CWBPING that will verify connectivity between the PC and the IBM i.

Comment: The  version is V5R4M0 with service pack is SI20465. I did researches, and I didn't find problems with this version using the same service pack. On this link http://bryanarancon.blogspot.com/2009/02/3-cwblm0011-internal-license-management.html they talk about this service pack SF66513 to resolve the issue. But I'm in SI20465 wich already have the updates of SF66513. Are There any problems with windows server 2003? Something that have to be solved to use with As400?

Comment: V5R4M0 is old - old enough to be officially end of life.  SI20465 is even older.  The most current service pack for V5R4 is SI37892.  Assuming that the reload of the server is using an old CD image, try loading SI37892.   http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/windows_sp.html  We would assume the problem is on the Windows Server since that's what has changed...